# How to set security header on 404 on Tomcat 9?

Tags: content-security-policy, tomcat9

Can anyone please teach me how to add security policies in error reply header?

I got this weirdo question is because my Tomcat 9 do reply security policy on normal access(Code 200 I mean), but not on my error reply (404 as example in this case).

So the contracted website inspector listed it as Low Risk and I have been asked to solve this(OH WT...).

I mean, that is a 404?? I don't even know why it needs secuirty policies on header. Can anyone help me or teach me how to talk them out?